# Getting textboxfor helper length using jquery in MVC

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, textbox

I've got Html.TextBoxFor and submit button. My intention is if text box is empty, the button is hidden. I was trying achieve that by this way:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tytul, new { id="tytulTextBox", @class = "tytulTextBoxDodajtresc" })

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var button = document.getElementById("DodajTrescButton");
            var myLength = $("#tytulTextBox").val().length;
            if (myLength > 0) {
                button.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    </script>
```

What I'am doing wrong ?. I'am very new in jquery, but it looks like using jquery will be the easiest way to achieve that what i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the else clause on your if

```
if (myLength > 0) {
                $(button).css("display","block");
            }
else{
$(button).css("display","none");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. I was trying to do as You said, but still the same, nothing happen..

Comment: Finally i resolved a problem. Your comment was very helpful, so many thanks :)